# Is the Keeper class available in the Awakening expansion?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I bought Dragon Age: Origins together with the Awakening expansion. When I started the game, I was given a choice whether I want to start with Dragon Age: Origins or with Awakening. I chose the Dragon Age: Origins storyline; is there an option for me to choose the Keeper class during the game, or is it only once I start the expansion storyline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will become available when you start the expansion.  That skill tree (among others) is only available at that point.

New characters made explicitly for the expansion (not from Origins carried forward) will have the expansion trees available immediately upon creation.